# how to upload and create @type/myLibrary for a JS library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, typescript-typings

**in short:**

I have a javascript library for which I have already create the d.ts file
what I cannot achieve is how to make it install with the `@type/*`

**details**

The repository I am trying to include to my project is https://github.com/thesunlover/javascript-blowfish

I already uploaded it the https://www.npmjs.com/ and I am already installing it via `npm install` .

My **problem** is that I don't know how to create the `npm install @types/javascript-blowfish` to work so that the command executes properly

should I upload the same repository as typings or I should change something in the `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@types` packages are sourced from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

You can upload your definition file to DefinitelyTyped and it will be automatically published to `@types` once merged into the master branch.

Comment: ok. I clone the repo, make a branch, commit the d.ts and request for a PR.
are there any specific requirements for the files or directories? should I only upload the d.ts file as well?

Comment: What if you created a library just to be used for local consumption, like a generic repository.  For example, I am using Web Storm and have a WebStormProjects folder which contains a GenericRepository folder and a SocialNetworkingApp folder.  I would like the SocialNetworkingApp to consume the GenericRepository.  How would I have to run npm install to make this happen?  I would also like this to be a typing, would that make a difference?